# Implement Ticket And Flight Relationship with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I want to implement relationship between Ticket and Flight relationship between the two entities.

A Flight has many tickets which is fine and can be achieved by

`Settickets = new HashSet(0);

```
@OneToMany
public Set<Ticket> getTickets() {
    return tickets;
}

public void setTickets(Set<Ticket> tickets) {
    this.tickets = tickets;
}`
```

But how should I implement Ticket has ONLY ONE Flight associated with it ?
I am not sure if Implementing like below would solve the problem. Inside Ticket,java

`Flight flight;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

           @JoinColumn(name="ticket_id")

    public Flight getFlight() {
        return flight;
    }`

```
public void setFlight(Flight flight) {
    this.flight = flight;
}
```

`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should go this way:

In `Flight`:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "flight")
Set<Ticket> tickets;
```

And in `Ticket`

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "FLIGHT_ID")
Flight flight;
```

Comment: Seems correct. Thanks. Can you please tell me what will mappedBy do, what will happen if I do not include it ?

Comment: From the documentation: To declare a side as not responsible for the relationship, the attribute mappedBy is used. mappedBy refers to the property name of the association on the owner side.